# how to check for a string object in java, correctly?

Tags: java

I have a class where I have a string object called `pGrade` and the `pGrade` is showing a 0 everytime it loads up. I just want to check and set it as a blank. But, for some reason my `pGrade` is being set to null and I tried to debug many times and watch it - still no luck to solve this issue. I am checking if `pGrade` is equals to 0 then set `pGrade` as a empty string. thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```
 if (pGrade.equals("0")) {
            pGrade = "";
        }
```

Comment: Since you `return this.label;` why does it matter what any of the other fields are? I would guess that is `null`, but you need to show us how you call this. Without any other context, we can only guess.

Comment: all objects including `label` there are values to it. It's  only in this class that `pGrade` set to null and not have a value.

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to set any instance fields in your `toString()` method. The `toString()` method should just return a string, and is not expected to change the object state. Perhaps you should write the code that changes `pGrade` somewhere else?

Comment: @RealSkeptic can I write `pGrade` outside the `toString()` method?

Comment: I think you have a bit of a mixup of terms. You can set the value of an instance variable like `pGrade` anywhere in a non-static method. But it's not recommended to do so in `toString()`. It's supposed to be done somewhere like the setter or any other method that manipulates the state. It's not clear if you are complaining about "0" or null, and when you get null, and what do you mean "everytime it loads". Your code doesn't show how you **use** the class so we can't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RealSkeptic thank you.

Comment: Instead of adding the way you use your code, you removed all your code. That is not helpful. The three lines you give us don't tell us where the `0` got there. They don't tell us when it changes to `null`. They don't show us if you actually get to this part of the code. Please read [ask] and try to improve your question with a [mcve].

Comment: if this is part of a large program then it wouldn't be easy for us to help. There might be somewhere in the program where it's being set back to zero. If this is a small program, then we can help if you show us more code....

Comment: @isaace  I am using the same `pGrade.equals("0")` at a different class. Also, I think I cant override `toString()` twice, right?

Answer (score 0):

When a string field has not been initialized explicitly, its value is `null`, not `"0"`.

So your check should be

```
if (pGrade == null)
    pGrade= "";
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize string like this

```
private String jobGroup = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

pGrade is the private member variable of your class JobSearchItem and it is of type String. In java the member variables of class are set to default values, so the default value of string will be null(These default values are assigned while creation of object).

So can't perform any operation on null value, and if you try to perform any operation on null then you will get NullPointerException.

So to avoid this you need to do the null check, and then you can assign some other value as shown below.

```
if (pGrade == null)
    pGrade= "";
```

Answer (score 0):

when using equals, put the constant string before,like this: “0”.equals(obj), if
obj is null, obj.equals(“0”) will throw en exception.